# The Moon is slowly moving away from the earth. Does this mean that a total solar eclipse wasn't possible at some point in earth's history?

Tags: astronomy, moon, earth, eclipse

When the moon was closer to earth, was it still possible to witness a total solar eclipse millions of years ago?  Or was the view-able space so small that it was impractical to even witness it?

Answer (score 6):

The moon is moving away from Earth. So in the past it was closer and its shadow was larger so a wider area experienced a total eclipse.

At some point in the future (in about 0.5 Billion years) a total solar eclipse will no longer be possible because the moon's shadow won't fall on the Earth.

Comment: I definitely agree with that. An article says that the moon is going away at about 3.5 cm/year. Might look small. But, a long count of years would take it away very easily. Its also slowing our rotation period. [This article](http://burro.astr.cwru.edu/Academics/Astr221/SolarSys/earthmoon.html) states the same: ***"In the distant future, the Earth will have a day which is 47 current days long, and the Moon will only be visible from one side of the Earth"*** Then, we might have to call out: "Hey Moon - Where r u?" when going to bed :-)